# Telerik RadListView for Nativescript not showing up

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a problem displaying RadListView from Telerik UI for Nativescript free library. I implemented sample from Getting started guide: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/getting-started

XML:

```
<Page loaded="onPageLoaded" xmlns:lv="nativescript-telerik-ui/listview" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <lv:RadListView items="{{ dataItems }}" >
        <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
            <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical"/>
        </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Label fontSize="20" text="{{ itemName }}"/>
                <Label fontSize="14" text="{{ itemDescription }}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    </lv:RadListView>
</Page>
```

Code-behind:

```
import viewModel = require("./getting-started-model");
export function onPageLoaded(args){
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new viewModel.ViewModel();
}
```

Model:

```
import {ObservableArray} from "data/observable-array";
import timer = require("timer");

export class ViewModel {

    private _items: ObservableArray<DataItem>;
    private _words = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"];

    constructor() {
    }

    get dataItems() {
        if (!this._items) {
            this._items = new ObservableArray<DataItem>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                this._items.push(new DataItem(i, "Item " + i, "This is item description."));
            }
        }
        return this._items;
    }

    private getRandomLengthString(){
        var sentenceLength = Math.round((Math.random() * 15));
        var result = this._words[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < sentenceLength; i++){
            result += (this._words[i % this._words.length] + " ");
        }
        return result;
    }
}

export class DataItem {
    public id: number;
    public itemName;
    public itemDescription;

    constructor(id: number, name: string, description: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.itemName = name;
        this.itemDescription = description;
    }
}
```

But all I am getting is blank page .. I am using NS version 2.3.0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think ViewModel has to be a sub-class of Observable.

Comment: Try giving `radListView` some height, had same issue in iOS. __OR__ `StackView` outside of `radListView`.

Comment: Yup, the problem was with the height .. lame .. :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the list height. Apparently, height has to be explicit, e.g.:

```
style="height: 500px"
```